# Trying to create a random game but doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

Under my form action, I called the textbox and buttons. It was suppose for the user to key in 2 values one being the highest value and another being the lowest value, it will then generate a random value between the lowest and the highest. The user will than guess the number if its correct it will print out the message correct

```
<form action="random" method="get" onSubmit="return validate()">
            Lowest number: 
            <input id="digit" type="text" name="lowestnumber" onchange="validate()"><br/>
            <br/><span id="numbers"></span>
    
            Highest number:
            <input id="digit1" type="text" name="highestnumber" onchange="validate()">
            <br/><span id="numbers1"></span>    
            
            <br/><input id="rand" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="Random()"><br/>
            <input id="guess" type="text" value="Random Number Generator">
          
            <br/>Enter your number<br/>
            <input id="textbox" type="text"><br/>
            <input id="guessing" type="button" value="Random" onclick="RandomNumber()"><br/>
            <br/><span id="correct"></span>
          
</form>
```

My script consist of the methods and functions to use, I think the problem lies at the RandomNumber() function, im not sure where did I go wrong, but please assist me

```
function validate() 
{
        
            var values = document.getElementById("digit").value;
            if(values<0)
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "This is not a number, number must be greater or equal to zero"
                    return false
            }
            else if (!(typeof +values && values >= 0)|| values.trim() == "") 
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "Fill in a number";
                    return false;
            }
            else if (values>=0)
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "";
            }
        
            var values1 = document.getElementById("digit1").value;
            if(values1<0)
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers1").innerHTML = "This is not a number, number must be greater or equal to zero"
                    return false
            }
            else if (!(typeof +values1 && values1 >= 0)|| values1.trim() == "") 
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers1").innerHTML = "Fill in a number";
                    return false;
            }
            else if (values >= values1)
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers1").innerHTML = "Highest number is smaller than lowest number";
                    return false;  
            }
            else if (values1 > values)
            {
                    document.getElementById("numbers1").innerHTML = "";
            }
            
            if((document.getElementById("digit").value>0) && (document.getElementById("digit1").value>0))
            {
            document.getElementById("rand").removeAttribute('disabled');
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById("rand").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
}
```

This is the function to generate a random number in between the lowest number and the highest number.

```
function Random()
        {
        
            var value1 = document.getElementById("digit").value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById("digit1").value;
            
            minvalue= Math.ceil(value1);
            maxvalue= Math.floor(value2);
            
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxvalue-minvalue)+1+minvalue);
            document.getElementById("guess").value=random;
            
        }
```

And this is the part where I assume it may have cause the entire program to stop working, its after I wrote down this codes and my web page doesn't perform the way I want it to be.

```
function RandomNumber()
        {
            var value3 = document.getElementById("digit").value;
            var value4 = document.getElementById("digit1").value;
            
            minvalue= Math.ceil(value3);
            maxvalue= Math.floor(value4);
            
            var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxvalue-minvalue)+1+minvalue);
            
            var maxtries=5;
            var counter=0;
            
            var true=document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            while(true!=random1)
            {
                document.getElementById("total").value=total;
                counter +=1;
                
                if(counter>maxtries)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="No more tries"
                    }
                if(true==random1)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Correct"
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome!
I'd like to help, but I'm getting lost in your code.
This is what I would do:
input for low with id,
input for high with id,
button for Go with onclick to validate,
input for guess with id and button for guess, both hidden until shown after validation,
div or span for messages with id.
----
validate to check low is number, high is number, and low is less than high, if not - appropriate message(s) into message element.
if ok - show guess elements and start counting guesses (global var),
guess to say "too big/small" or "correct".

Comment: @iAmOren alright will give it a try

Comment: You can limit input to digits only.
element's value is a string.
parseInt or just +element.value (if string of digits).

Comment: @iAmOren do you know how I am able to call my function Random() under function RandomNumber() ??

Comment: @iAmOren actually I'm not sure what you mean on your 1st comment.

Comment: At the last line of `Random` add `return random;`, and in `RandomNumber`, use like so:
`r=Random();`.

Comment: @iAmOren it still doesn't work, I think its my function RandomNumber() which is causing my program to not work

Comment: I think you over-did the code.
I do that a lot too.
So, I was trying to point you to a "simpler" approach.
I think: what do I want?
What is needed for that?
How do I want it to work?
And I try to keep it simple.
Here: you don't need to call validate from onchange - just make a button to "go" and validate there.

Comment: Move `var counter=0;` out of the function - otherwise, it will start at 0 again and again.
As I've said - it's a bit hard for me to follow your code.

Comment: @iAmOren  what do you mean by don't need to call validate from on change?

Comment: @iAmOren the reason why I have counter=0 is because the user only has 5 tries to guess the number correctly so each time the person keys in the wrong number it will add 1 to it

Comment: wrong place to set counter to 0

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code I see a couple of red flags.
E.g. `true` is a reserved keywoard in JS, you can't assign a value to it:

```
var true=document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

This must throw an error in your development console.

Also in your loop `while(true!=random1)` neither `true` or `random1` are reassigned, so if true in the beginning, the condition will never become false, hence the loop is never left in this case!

In general you should try to narrow your issue down, look at the errors and rather ask for help on smaller snippets where you ask concrete questions. With a statement like `my web page doesn't perform the way I want it to be` it is hard to provide help.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is after changing true to another name. Before having the RandomNumber() method, it allows me to generate a random number, but after having the RandomNumber() method, the random generator doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm new to this